# Error java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an error that I don't understand even after researching similar errors on the internet.
I create an ArrayList of integer, and then simply try to read it with .get(), getting the error `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer` even though I don't use any Strings with this ArrayList.

Here is the part of the code:

```
package com.example.reixa.todolist;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ListActivity extends Activity {

LinearLayout        linearList;
CheckBox            checkBox;
ArrayList<String>   checkList= new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer>  checkState = new ArrayList<>();
Bundle              bundle;
String              stuff;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
    readItems();
    linearList = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_list);
    bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    stuff = bundle.getString("name");

    for (int i = 0; i < checkList.size(); i++)
    {
        checkBox = new CheckBox(this);
        checkBox.setId(i);
        checkBox.setText(checkList.get(i));
        checkBox.setOnClickListener(getOnClickSomething(checkBox));
        linearList.addView(checkBox);
        if (checkState.get(i) == 0)  // error here
            checkBox.setChecked(!checkBox.isChecked());

    }
}

public void onAddItem(View v) {
    EditText etNewItem = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNewItem);
    String itemText = etNewItem.getText().toString();
    checkList.add(itemText);
    checkState.add(0);
    etNewItem.setText("");
    writeItems();

    checkBox = new CheckBox(this);
    checkBox.setId(checkList.size());
    checkBox.setText(itemText);
    checkBox.setOnClickListener(getOnClickSomething(checkBox));
    linearList.addView(checkBox);
}

View.OnClickListener getOnClickSomething(final Button button) {
    return new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("ON CLICK", "CheckBox ID: " + button.getId() + " Text: " + button.getText().toString());
            if (checkState.get(button.getId()) == 0)
                checkState.set(button.getId(), 1);
            else
                checkState.set(button.getId(), 0);
        }
    };
}

private void readItems() {
    File filesDir = getFilesDir();

    bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    stuff = bundle.getString("name");

    File todoFile = new File(filesDir, stuff);
    try {
        checkList = new ArrayList<>(FileUtils.readLines(todoFile));
        checkState = new ArrayList<>(FileUtils.readLines(todoFile));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        checkList = new ArrayList<>();
        checkState = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}

private void writeItems() {
    File filesDir = getFilesDir();
    bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    stuff = bundle.getString("name");

    File todoFile = new File(filesDir, stuff);
    try {
        FileUtils.writeLines(todoFile, checkList);
        FileUtils.writeLines(todoFile, checkState);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

The ArrayList in question is `checkState` and the line where the error happens is `if (checkState.get(i) == 0)`.

Comment: Post full stacktrace

Comment: There doesn't look like there's anything wrong with this code snippet.

Comment: How do you fill data into your `ArrayList`s?

Comment: I added the full page code, sorry for not doing this from start.

Comment: @EtienneMoussillac Please paste the stack trace/ full error message from your console.

Comment: Thanks for the code. The next very good thing to do in case of an exception is to post the stacktrace and mark in the code which line the stacktrace refers to. The second line of the stacktrace typically says something like `at fr.your.package.YourClass.yourMethod(YourClass.java:16)`. If so, when you tell us which line of the posted code is line 16 of YourClass.java, we’ll know a lot more.

Comment: You've done research of that error but haven't check your own code *what* you put in it and *where* it happens? When one stranger can find that issue by just looking at this code, then you should have found that with a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get this exception it means that somehow you have loaded `String` into the `ArrayList` `checkState`, and according to your current code, the most suspicious part is the method `readItems` in which you load `checkState` as next:

```
// Here is your problem, you load it using String instead of Integer
checkState = new ArrayList<>(FileUtils.readLines(todoFile));
```

Knowing that you initialize `checkList` which is an `ArrayList` of `String` the exact same way, it is obvious that one of the lists would contain objects of the wrong type.

Comment: this must be the reason, however as `checkState` is of type `List<Integer>` and the `ArrayList` constructor takes a `Collection<? extends E>` (where `E` is in this case `Integer`), how does it accept a `Collection<String>` without a compile error?

Comment: You are right, that part was the problem.  I modified it to make it work. Thanks!

Comment: @NicolasFilotto That can't be. That method is from the Apache Commons, and [it seems to return a `List<String>`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readLines(java.io.File)).

Comment: @EtienneMoussillac Are you using an older version of the Commons? Older versions used the raw type `List`, which is not type safe and you should update. If you had used a version that returned `List<String>` (as it should) your code would not have compiled. Also, the [`readLines(File)` method is deprecated](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readLines(java.io.File)) - you should avoid using it.

Comment: That info would help you much here, since you're interessted in the return type. ;P

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies here

```
checkState = new ArrayList<>(FileUtils.readLines(todoFile));
```

**readLines()**  returns `List<String>`
Where as your checkState is of type `List<Integer>` and hence the ClassCastException.

Answer (score -2):

You declared checkList as an array of String. You cannot check if a String equals an Integer (or int) using ==. If you want to compare them, you either need to turn the String to an int, or turn the int to a string.

If checkList contains a number in String format, you can do this.

```
if(Integer.parseInt(checkState.get(0)) == 0)
```

Or if it really is a string then you could do this

```
if(checkState.get(0).equals("0"))
```

Or if you were really meaning to check the list size you could do this

```
if(checkState.size() == 0)
```

Comment: No. They are using `checkState`, which is an `ArrayList<Integer>`.

Comment: Just realized that. When he said he was getting a class cast from String to int I got mixed up.